# GtkTreeView's row-activated and cursor-changed signals

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I have a treeview and I am watching for the `cursor-changed` and `row-activated` signals.  The problem is that in order to trigger the row-activate I first have to click on the row (triggering `cursor-changed`) and then do the double click, requiring 3 clicks.

Is there a way to respond to both signals with 2 clicks?

Answer (score 4):

It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. I guess you're trying to respond to the user changing the selection in the treeview.

If this is the case, connect to the `[changed][1]` signal on the `gtk.TreeSelection`:

```
selection = treeview.get_selection()
selection.connect('changed', self.on_treeview_selection_changed)
```

As far as I can tell, this is not possible using the glade interface designer.

If, however, you are trying to do something else entirely, please add some more information.

Comment: Is there a way to connect this signal from Glade?

Answer (score 3):

The `cursor-changed` signal is emitted even when single clicking on the same (selected) row. Still, the `row-activated` signal is emitted when you double click on a row, whether it was selected before the double click or not. Thus you don't need 3 clicks to trigger a `row-activated`.

As Jon mentioned, you want to connect to the selection's `changed` signal in stead of `cursor-changed`.